# Is it possible to exclude specific components in a form or panelGroup from being executed/rendered

Tags: jsf-2

I am working on an xhtml page that containt one very big form.
Within this form there is a loop driven from database results. Each row returned has a corresponding fragment which contains form inputs contributing to the outer form.I have wrapped this entire structure in a panelGroup for easy updating via Ajax. The problem is that these fragments each contain multiple modal dialogs which have fields that should be submitted independently from the outer structure

Is there any technique/ or something in omnifaces that can allow me to exclude specific components from the execute/render process?

Comment: `rendered` attribute allow you exclude specific component from rendering. If problem is with modal dialog(s), then why not move those modal dialog(s) outside form?

Comment: Yes, I have done exactly that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rendered` attribute allow to exclude component from rendering. Modal dialog(s) can be moved outside form.